# c++ vector of vectors atomic write and read with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, mutex, atomic

I have a problem and it doesn't seem that I can solve it.

I have two vector of vectors in which I store data. But I also using threads to speed up the updateing of values(the size is unchanged, just if there's a number that is less than the original it rewrites to that).

But the threads are wrong without atomicity.

Can you help me in what should I do?

1. Should I use just std::atomic_int
    If so, then how should I use the load and store functions or maybe something else? I give my vectors to the thread like so in .h:

   `void for_thread_function(std::vector<std::vector<int>> * DATA1,td::vector<std::vector<int>> * DATA2 /*other params*/)`

   in .cpp:

   `std::thread thread (&MY_PROBLEM::for_thread_function, this, &DATA1, &DATA2, /*other params*/);`
2. Should I use mutex-es? Then which one, and again how to use it on two data source? Or can you give me a little example, I didn't use muteces (?) at all before.
3. Should I use the combination of the first two? And how??
4. Other

Could you give me an explanation of why is *that* option is the best?

Thank you for your help I'm really lost in the woods about this stuff.

**EDIT:** I use the threads to calculate BFS from different starting point. So I need to pass the entire matrix. I have relatively large datasets (one table with cost and the other is from which starting point is that vertex the nearest)

Comment: Give each sub vector to its own thread for processing?

Comment: Instead of passing a pointer to the vectors, pass pointers to internal ranges within the vectors, a unique range per thread. That should avoid the need for synchronization.

Comment: "But the threads are wrong without atomicity" - ehh, yes, of course. You *need* to synchronise access to stuff. Either by using atomics, mutexes or some other synchronization primitive or having seperate copies of data.. Otherwise, how would you ever be confident in your results? If threads can just trample on each others data and read partially updated values, no good will ever come from your program. You may be *lucky* in a few runs, but you *want* guarantees.

Comment: Can you specify more details of the problem, or give an example problem that you want to solve? It is a little bit foggy..

Comment: I try to avoid multithread sync issues by accumulating information to be written in a common area inside a space set aside and passed to each thread. Then, when all the worker threads exit I update things from this area. This is very effective when a problem allows it.